# Something is adding upper folders in zip file

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I need to get all files from one directory(and there aren't any subfolders) and put them in a zip file

```
def zipDirectory(pathToDirectory, zipFile):

    for entry in os.listdir(pathToDirectory + "/"):
        if os.path.isfile(pathToDirectory + "/" + entry):
            print(pathToDirectory + "/" + entry)
            zipFile.write(pathToDirectory + "/" + entry)
```

So, this function takes path to directory, which files I should zip, and zip file to write in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your talking about a folder same as `pathToDirectory` being added to the zip file.

For example, if I have this folder:

```
parent
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3
```

Your function would create a zip file with a *parent* folder.

If you looked at the docs for the [`ZipFile.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) function, it accepts an `arcname` parameter that specifies how the file will be written into the archive. If you don't set it, it is auto-set to be the same as `filename`, which in your case is `pathToDirectory + "/" + entry`, which results in a folder being created.

Just specify an `arcname` to be the same as `entry`:

```
def zipDirectory(pathToDirectory, zipFile):
    for entry in os.listdir(pathToDirectory):
        entryPath = os.path.join(pathToDirectory, entry)
        if os.path.isfile(entryPath):
            print(entryPath)
            zipFile.write(entryPath, arcname=entry)

zipDirectory("parent", ZipFile("parent.zip", "w"))
```